# Google API discovery possible within Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-api, task-queue

I want to access an external Google API through a GAS trigger. Is it possible/advisable to use something like the [javascript Google API client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client), adapted for the GAS context, instead of manually using URL Fetch, as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) ?

PS. I am trying to hit the Google App Engine TaskQueue service via its REST API.

Comment: Is this the API you are talking about?   [Google Task Queue Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/)

Comment: Also found this API.  [Services](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/taskqueue/v1beta2/)

Answer (score 1):

In the Apps Script Code Editor, under the RESOURCES, ADVANCED GOOGLE SERVICES menu, you can enable different API's.  I don't see an Advanced Service for anything the resembles a Task Queue.  There is a **Tasks API**, but that's for Task List, which is very different than the Task Queue.

So, I don't think you have any choice but to use the REST API with `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` in server side `gs` code in Apps Script.

As far as the trigger is concerned, you might want to look at quota limits, if you're going to be running it a lot, or running code that takes a long time to run.

Comment: Thanks Sandy, that was my conclusion as well, but I was hoping to be able to use this library: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client  to wrap the raw HTTP calls. But the main problem with UrlFetchApp as far as I can tell, is I need to OAuth using a service account, without user intervention (since it will be called in a trigger). I don't see how to do this with UrlFetchApp or the now preferred OAuth2 library for GAS.

Comment: That a JavaScript **CLIENT** library.  That goes into HTML, and runs in the browser of the users computer.  You can create an HTML App with Apps Script, but that library can't be used with server side code.

Comment: Yes, good point - to be precise, I am asking if there is an _adaptation_ of this library (or the node.js one) for the GAS environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external APIs with OAUTH2 as outlined here: [apps-script-oauth2](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2)

It's just not built-in, but you can easily add it as a library as mentioned in the Readme.